# Однородные глаголы в повелительном наклонении - нужна ли запятая?

Tags: пунктуация

Нужна ли запятая между повелительными глаголами "пойди и залезь"?

Answer (score 3):

Запятая не нужна.

В данном случае корректно говорить об однородных определенно-личных предложениях, в которых сказуемое выражено повелительной формой глагола.

При наличии одиночного союза И запятая не ставится (фактически такие предложения приравниваются к однородным членам).